# Select * Where Date 1 and Date 2 elapsed time is greater than

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Columns in the same table: CREATED DATE and APPROVED DATE

In my Select statement, I would like to return only records Where the elapsed time between CREATED DATE and APPROVED DATE is greater than 2 days, or where the APPROVED DATE is greater than CREATED DATE by 2 days.

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATEDIFF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp)

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(created_date, approved_date) > 2 OR DATEDIFF(approved_date, created_date) > 2
```

Comment: DATEDIFF worked thanks, just be advised it needs 3 arguments to specify the measure of time 

Where DATEDIFF(day, created_date, approved_date) > 2

Comment: In SQL server you need 3 [see link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

Comment: @C.Timmerman Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how precisely you need to know:

If the "date" columns are dates:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(`APPROVED DATE`, `CREATED DATE`) > 2
```

If the "date" columns are timestamps and you want to know the second 2 days have passed:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `CREATED DATE`, `APPROVED DATE`) > 2
```